# Execute an shell script with sudo inside from php

Tags: shell, sudo, php, exec

I want to execute a command line command as root from a php file. In my case I want to view the crontab file in my php page.

Running the `sudo` command in php is not recommended and on my raspberry pi with raspberry pi OS the php line

```
echo (shell_exec("sudo more /var/spool/cron/crontabs/pi"));
```

does not work. So I created a shell script:

**crontab.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start Crontab"
sudo more /var/spool/cron/crontabs/pi
echo "End Crontab"
```

and I created a php page:
**crontab.php**

```
<?php
echo "Get Current User: " . get_current_user();
echo "<br>Who am I: ".(exec("whoami"));
echo "<br>";
echo (shell_exec("/var/www/html/cmd/crontab.sh"));
?>
```

When I execute the crontab.sh in the command line. It seems to work. Because I see the crontab text.
When I load the php page. I do not see the crontab text. I only see

```
Get Current User: pi
Who am I: www-data
Start Crontab End Crontab
```

What can I do?
I had a cron that used `rsync` to copy the `crontab -e` file to a `cron.txt` file every hour. It worked but i do not want to view an (old) copy.

edit: My problem is that the task that starts with sudo gives zero output. In the comments I got the suggestion to use `sudo crontab -l`. That's better than the line I used because it gives the root crontab and I just did not know of the `-l` solution. But the problem is still there. There is zero output.

Comment: What do you mean by "_does not work_"? Error messages? Zero output? Please [tell us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/643455/edit)

Comment: Instead of using user pi's crontab, use root's:  `sudo crontab -e`  That way, your script already has root access and you don't need to use `sudo`.

Comment: Using `more` does not make sense since a web page isn't interactive. You probably want `crontab -l` or `sudo crontab -l -u pi`. (Or `sudo cat  /var/spool/cron/crontabs/pi`, though technically that only works by accident and other distributions have their crontabs in other locations.)

Comment: The sudo command does give zero output. I can put a line in the .sh file that starts with sudo and there is zero output in the php file. When I put a rsync command it is also not executed.  But from the command line it works. To update my question: How can I get output of a line that has to start with sudo?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found out how to perform a sudo task in php (apache2) or in a shell script executed from php (apache2).

The trick is with `sudo visudo`
I found that comment a lot. But I used it wrong!
The script that should be allowed to perform a sudo task must not me my own .sh file. But the full path to the command.

For crontab and user:www-data that is:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab
```

When somebody has the same problem,I hope they read that faster than I did.

Comment: That will indirectly give your web server full rights to your system as root. I hope you don't have anything important on it

Comment: It's on my private network. I will be save if it is not accessible from the internet?

Comment: @MacQwerty, I recommend never doing things that build bad habits.